# Magento 2 - how to upload an image from admin CRUD

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, image, save, upload

I'm new to Magento, created a simple CRUD module, which have a name, description and logo columns, Name and description are saving to the DB without any problems, but I need help on how to upload an image.
Here is my whole module file structure, and code of Save controller,
Thanks everyone for helping me!

[image]

```
<?php
namespace Elogic\Vendors\Controller\Adminhtml\Vendors;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Save extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Elogic\Vendors\Model\Vendors
     */
    protected $_model;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param \Elogic\Vendors\Model\Vendors $model
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Elogic\Vendors\Model\Vendors $model
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_model = $model;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Elogic_Vendors::vendors_save');
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($data) {
            /** @var \Elogic\Vendors\Model\Vendors $model */
            $model = $this->_model;

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            if ($id) {
                $model->load($id);
            }

            $model->setData($data);

            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'vendors_vendors_prepare_save',
                ['vendors' => $model, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]
            );
            try {
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Vendor saved'));
                $this->_getSession()->setFormData(false);
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving vendor'));
            }

            $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['entity_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Uploading the product image in Magento 2**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

protected $_fileUploaderFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
    Action\Context $context

) {

    $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute(){

    $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);

    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);

    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

    $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)

    ->getAbsolutePath('images/');

    $uploader->save($path);

}
```

I hope this will help. If you still find any difficulty please let me know